# Nginx whenever loading static 404 is returened

Tags: nginx

I have an image om the disk saved on the path: `/usr/volumes/rgd/app/images/image-name`.
when ever someone calls to `domain.com/img/some-image-name` I want to show the image.
when ever someone calls to `domain.com/anythingelse` I want to show the proxy_pass.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    location ~/img/ {
         try_files $uri /usr/volumes/rgd/app/images/$uri =404;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://app:3000;
        ...
    }
}
```

So `domain.com/img/testimg` should return the image: `/usr/volumes/rgd/app/images/testimg` **the image is placed at the correct location in the nginx server**.

I am getting error 404. the proxy_pass works as expected.

**UPDATE**
I have fixed it, to:

```
location ~^/img/(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri /usr/volumes/rgd/app/images/$1 =404;
}
```

`$ ls -la /usr/volumes/rgd/app/images/`
`-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         14717 Dec 26 14:31 /usr/volumes/rgd/app/images/d5085ad47099ed8c08bd`

when i access `domain.com/img/d5085ad47099ed8c08bd` I get 404.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling NGINX to check this directory

```
/usr/volumes/rgd/app/images/img/
```

instead of this

```
/usr/volumes/rgd/app/images/
```

You must extract only part of url after "/img/" using regular expression with capture:

```
location ~^/img/(.*)$ {
    root /usr/volumes/rgd/app;
    try_files $uri /images/$1 =404;
}
```

This tell the NGINX to process all URLs that begins with "/img/" and contains anything after it. Grab the part after "/img/" and chcek this location "usr/volumes/rgd/app/images/my_grabbed_part_from_url".

Comment: Check updated answer. try_files probably doesn't support absolute paths. This works for me.